# Python: Cannot find the right encoding to print Tableau result

Tags: python, unicode

I want to print the result of crosstabs from Tableau worksheet, it contains some Tranditional Chinese words in it.

```
import sys
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')
.
.
.
view_data_raw = querying.get_view_data_dataframe(
    conn, view_id=visual_c_id)
print(view_data_raw.to_string()) #A
print(view_data_raw.to_string().encode(encoding='utf-8')) #B
print(view_data_raw.to_string().encode(encoding='cp1252')) #C
print(view_data_raw.to_string().encode(encoding='gbk')) #D
```

#A

```
2023å¹´4æ1æ¥                     #it should be 2023年4月1日
```

#B

```
2023\xc3\xa5\xc2\xb9\xc2\xb44\xc3\xa6\xc2\x9c\xc2\x881\xc3\xa6\xc2\x97\xc2\xa5      #it should be 2023年4月1日
```

#C

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 8-9: character maps to <undefined>
```

#D

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character '\xe4' in position 4: illegal multibyte sequence
```

I tried to decode and encode several times but it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: What was the result of `print(repr(view_data_raw))`?  You didn't have a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution:

```
print(view_data_raw.to_string().encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode())
```